# How to traverse path using variable in linux shells script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I wrote a shell script to copy current date's files and place them in target folder with current date name, target folder path contains variable. This path works fine when i manually run the cd or cp command, but in shell script, while copying through cp, directory with variable is not recognized.

```
d=`date +%b' '%d`
td=`date +%d%b%Y`
cd /filenet/shared/logs
mkdir $td
cd $td
mkdir icn02 icn03 GC cpe01 cpe02 cpe03 cpeb01 cpeb02 icn01 css01 css02 http01 http02 http03

ssh hostname <<'ENDSSH'
cd /<some_path>
ls -ltrh | grep "$d" | awk {'print $9'} | xargs cp -t /filenet/shared/logs/"${td}"/GC
ENDSSH
```

Error

```
-ksh[2]: td: not found [No such file or directory]
cp: failed to access ‘/filenet/shared/logs//GC’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: ksh is not bash.

Comment: I have used #!/bin/ksh
echo $0
bash

Comment: Your `$d` inside the heredoc evaluates to a **remote** variable named `d`, not the **local** variable by that name.

Comment: Don't pipe `grep` to `awk`.  `... | grep pattern | awk '{cmd}'` is identical to `... | awk '/pattern/{cmd}'`.

Answer (score 3):

A corrected version of this script may look more like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^- ksh93 also allowable; /bin/sh is not.

d=$(date '+%b %d')      || exit
td=$(date '+%d%b%Y')    || exit

cd /filenet/shared/logs || exit
mkdir -p -- "$td"       || exit
cd "$td"                || exit
mkdir -p -- icn02 icn03 GC cpe01 cpe02 cpe03 cpeb01 cpeb02 icn01 css01 css02 http01 http02 http03 || exit

# these should only fail if you're using a shell that isn't either bash or ksh93
d_q=$(printf '%q' "$d")   || exit
td_q=$(printf '%q' "$td") || exit

ssh hostname "bash -s ${d_q} ${td_q}" <<'ENDSSH'
d=$1
td=$2
cd /wherever || exit
find . -name "*${d}*" -exec cp -t "/filenet/shared/logs/${td}/GC" -- {} +
ENDSSH
```

Note:

- When using a quoted heredoc (`<<'ENDSSH'`), expansions within the heredoc are not honored. To copy variables across, move them out-of-band -- here, we use `printf %q` to generate escaped copies of our values which are `eval`-safe, and use `bash -s` to put those in the shell command line (`$1` and `$2`).
- [**Never, ever grep or parse the output of `ls`**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Thank you Charles, I will try this and will let all know.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to replace

```
$(td)
```

with

```
${td}
```

Comment: I tried that too
tried using all like  $(td) , ${td} "${td}", $td

its works fine as expected when running command manually, but it doesn't works when put in script

Comment: The OP appears to have edited the question in such a manner as to remove the context that made this answer make sense.